# Optimal distibution of a roots of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, optimization

Let $p(x)$ be a monic polynomial with $n$ complex roots:

$$
p(x)=(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)\cdots(x-\lambda_n), \qquad \lambda_i \in \mathbb{C},
$$

Define
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\big(1+|x|^{2}\big)^n}|p(x)|^2.
$$

Question: for some fixed $n$, is there some simple method/algorithm to find the $n$ complex numbers $\lambda_i$ that make $\max_{x\in \mathbb{C}}f(x)$ the lowest possible?

Comment: Must the $\lambda_i$ be distinct, or do you allow repeated roots?

Comment: @DanielFischer, repeated roots are allowed

Comment: In that case, $\lambda_1 = \dotsc = \lambda_n = 0$ is an optimal selection of roots (don't know if it's the only optimum; it is for $n = 1$). We always have $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1$, and for $p(x) = x^n$ we have $f(x) = \frac{\lvert x\rvert^{2n}}{(1+\lvert x\rvert^2)^n} < 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, It is correct, thanks. However I would like to have another solution different from $\lambda_1=\ldots=\lambda_n=0$? For example for $n=2$, $\lambda_1=a$, and $\lambda_2=-a$ is another solution. Any idea for larger $n$?